# Whether to use cookie or session for sending data between PHP files?

Tags: php, android

I'm designing an app using quite a lot of php pages and thought it'd be better

If I could use some of the php pages within processing of data at the server itself, using headers.

Then, I will not be able to send values through HashMaps from Httpclient at Android

So I'm trying to use cookies or sessions to send information inbetween.

But I'm confused whether this Android Httpclient has some kind of browser or else.

As far as I know cookies are saved at the browsers and sessions are saved at servers?

Does that mean:

1. I am not able to use cookies at Android apps?
2. If there are lots of session users are my servers going to get slow?
3. Is there a preference between the two if both are Available?

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly, it seems to me that you've still got a lot of *application design* work yet to do!  **:-)**

Any PHP (or, any other) language, running on your web server, is going to talk in just one way:  "HTTP."  That means data sent by GET or POST, accompanied by cookies, as the protocol prescribes.

Most commonly, your Android app will use the same general techniques for talking to an HTTP server that JavaScript does, namely, "AJAX."  It will use encoding techniques like "JSON."

Yes, "cookies" are tokens ... short strings ... held by the browser and sent with each request.  Servers use these tokens (or, other methods) to locate "session" information, which they store.

I suggest that you do a *lot* more reading, web-surfing, and then, *planning* of how you intend for your application to operate.  And, by all means, look in places like GitHub for *existing* Android applications that you can freely download and study. ("All of this stuff has been done before, many times, and they've shared their source-code with you. Go find out how *they* did it.")